# ffmpeg 2 pass encoding- understand the statistics in the output .log file

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, codec, x264

I am using 2 pass encoder to encode my input video with a target bitrate.
I want to get the encoder (x264) statistics from the first pass- these statistics are written to ffmpeg2pass.log
the output for each frame looks like that:

in:2 out:2 type:B dur:2 cpbdur:2 q:28.41 aq:25.07 tex:4721 mv:2357 misc:2266 imb:24 pmb:527 smb:3049 d:- ref:0 ;

How can I found is the meaning of each value? (for example, mv is motion vectors, but what is the meaning of misc, imb, pmb etc.?)

ffmpeg command used:
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p16le -s:v 1280x720 -i "input_file.yuv" -c:v libx264 -pass 1 -stats -vstats -passlogfile "log_file_prefix" -f mp4 -y "output.mp4" &&
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p16le -s:v 1280x720 -i "input_file.yuv" -c:v libx264 -pass 2  -passlogfile "log_file_prefix" -y "output.mp4"

Comment: Take a look at https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/blob/master/encoder/ratecontrol.c#L1852 along with https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/blob/master/common/common.h.

Answer (score 0):

In: display/input frame number

Out: coded frame number

Type: frame type

q: frame quantization value

Tex: the bit size used for residual

Mv: bit size for mvs

Misc: for other bit sizes

Imb: number of internal macroblocks

Pmb: number of inter macroblocks

Smb: skip the number of skip macroblocks

d: the best mode for this frame

Ref: the number of times each ref is used in the list

w: the optimal weight of this frame (if the weight is turned on)